# Find $a$ so that the quadratic polynomial with roots $a$ and $a^2$ has the max possible slope at $x=0$.

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, polynomials, optimization, roots

I think I have the answer, but it's a tricky problem, so I'm looking for verification here.

Find a number $a$ so that the quadratic polynomial with roots $a$ and $a^2$ has the maximum possible slope at the point $x = 0.$

First, a quadratic polynomial with roots $a$ and $a^2$ is $$f(x) = (x - a)(x-a^2) = x^2 - ax - a^2x + a^3.$$

Then we note that the derivative of $f(x)$ is $$f'(x) = 2x - a - a^2.$$

Then we want to find the value $a$ that gives the maximum slope at $$f'(0) = -a - a^2.$$

So now we can think about this as a function of $a,$ 
$$g(a) = -a - a^2.$$
The derivative of this function is $$g'(a) = -1 - 2a,$$
which has a critical point at $a = -\frac{1}{2},$ which is in fact a global maximum of $g(a).$

The max slope is then $g(-\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{4},$ which isn't a very big slope.

Comment: *The* quadratic polynomial, with roots $a$ and $a^2$???

Comment: You forgot that there is a family of such polynomials $f(x)=c(x-a)(x-a^2)$ where $c$ is some constant

Comment: I think that I haven't understood your doubt. Your reasoning is indeed correct. However, you have excluded some cases as @Vasya spotted.

Comment: @Vasya That makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: There must be some additional condition hidden within the phrase “the quadratic polynomial.” For some values of the coefficient of $x^2$, it’s impossible to maximize the slope at $x=0$.

Comment: If $c<0$ you found the $a$ that minimizes the slope at 0